# What are the benefits of using the Nestjs testing module for unit tests?

Tags: nestjs

In the [Nestjs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#testing-utilities), they suggest using their Test module for instantiating any objects used for testing, like so:

```
const adoptionServiceMock = {
  adoptCat: jest.fn()
};

const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [CatsService, { provider: AdoptionService, useValue: adoptionServiceMock }],
}).compile();

catsService = moduleRef.get<CatsService>(CatsService);
```

What is the benefit of doing it this way, as opposed to regular instantiation? Here's an example of the regular way:

```
const adoptionServiceMock = {
  adoptCat: jest.fn()
} as AdoptionService;

catsService = new CatsService(adoptionService);
```

I'm specifically referring to using `catsService = moduleRef.get<CatsService>(CatsService)` instead of `new`ing up a CatsService.

The one thing I can think of is that it does object instantiation the same way Nestjs would do it in production - with DI. If you forget to add `Inject()` on CatsService or AdoptionService, the test will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't find benefit in it, you absolutely can use whatever method you prefer for mocking. The `Test.createTestingModule` is there to provide uniformity between Nest projects and to provide an easy way to give mocks to the classes without having to use `as whatever`, but if you prefer that method, then go for it.

It becomes more powerful out at the e2e/integration level where you can mock guards and other enhancers with fluent methods, but again, the final test implementation is absolutely up to you.

I personally like it cause I can delegate Nest to create providers based off of a class and mock things from there, like a TypeORM repository can be created as

```js
{
  provide: getRepositoryToken(EntityClass),
  useClass: Repository,
}
```

No need to extensively create a lot of methods, then later I can use `jest.spyOn()` or `jest.fn()` to override the default functionality.